# Conditional to show entry by date range?

Tags: conditionals, date

Have an instance where there are two entries - one needs to be shown for six months of the year and the other for the second six months.... looking at a conditional which essentially says:

> if date_range = January-June
>
> Show this
>
> If else
>
> Show this

Is it doable with EE's native conditionals or does it need another approach?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The following conditional will achieve what you want:

```
{if {current_time format="%m"} <= 6}
  <p>do Jan through June</p>
{if:else}
  <p>do July through December</p>
{/if}
```

---

**Edit:** Replying to request for March-thru-September date range:

Since the `%m` flag on the date format represents each month as a number (and conveniently *one-based* at that), to achieve what you would like you would simply change the code to:

```
{if {current_time format="%m"} >= 3 && {current_time format="%m"} <= 9}
    <p>do March through September</p>
{if:else}
    <p>do January, February, October, November or December</p>
{/if}
```

Comment: Is there any way to modify this conditional to a specific range? Say March to September for example?

Comment: See revised answer.